# Sveltekit Form with iframe event variable not visible outside script

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

Scope of the Issue. I have a Sveltekit form with an embedded element that renders an Iframe onMount. This form as an embedded {# browser} that holds the script calling the iframe.

The element is rendering the variable i need but is only usable inside the script of the form. How do i use the variable generated by the iframe outside the script.

The end goal would be to either put the value in a hidden input and transmit as formData or simply transfer to the page.server.

```
<form>
                {#if browser}
            <script>                   
                // declare ticket id variable
                var ticketid = "";
                
                elements.on('done', function (event) {
                    //console.log(event);
                    let responseData = event.data;
                    ticket = responseData.id;                        
                    console.log("Ticket:", ticket); // checks out good 23/09/25
                    // Use a reactive declaration to expose formData to the template
                    $: {
                        if (ticket) {
                           ticketid = ticket;
                    }
                    }
                });

         
                
            </script> 

            {/if} 
            <h5>Ticket: {ticketid}</h5>
            <input type="hidden" name="ticketid" value={ticketid}>
```

Comment: You can only have one "special" `<script>` and it has to be at the top level of the component. All other scripts will not support any Svelte features. Also, `$:` will never work anywhere except at the top level within said top-level script.

Comment: I am an idiot. I knew that. Ive been working on this for days on and off and all i had to do was throw it on an onMount in the script tag. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Answered: Everything need to go in the main Script tag or everything is going to not work correctly.